# How to get the submitted <select> option in a html page where multiple forms (and select fields) are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having troubles in getting the submitted option in a html page where I create dynamically a number of forms, the corresponding `<select>` and the `<option>` values within it.

This is **my html**

```
<div class="inputs_container">
</div>
```

**my js**:

```
 var data = {
        "name": "forest",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "input_1", "formats": ["JPG"]
            },
            {
                "name": "input_2", "formats": ["TXT","ODT"]
            }
        ]
}
var data_files = {
    "resources": [
        {"name": "file_1.jpg", "format": "JPG"},
        {"name": "file_2.jpg", "format": "JPG"},
        {"name": "text_1.txt", "format": "TXT"},
        {"name": "text_2.txt", "format": "TXT"},
        {"name": "odt_1.odt", "format": "ODT"},
        {"name": "odt_2.odt", "format": "ODT"}
    ]
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $.each(data.inputs, function(i, input) {
        let format_in = input.formats;
        var form_id = input.name;
        var select_id = form_id + "_id";
        var select_name = form_id + "_name";
        
        let $h5 = $(`<h5>Select ${input.formats} file</h5>`).appendTo('.inputs_container');
        $('<form>', {
            "id": form_id,
            "html": '<div class="input_field s12 l6"> <select id="' + select_id + '" name= "' + select_name +'">  </select> </div> <div class="col s12 l6"><button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button> </div>'
    }).appendTo(`.inputs_container`);

        var select = document.getElementById(select_id);
        var file_list_URI =  serverURI + "/resources?formats=" + format_in + "";
        $.getJSON(file_list_URI, function(file){
            $.each(file.resources, function(j, fieldopt){
                select.add(new Option(fieldopt.name, fieldopt.name));
            }); // each
            M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
            var input_form = document.getElementById(form_id);
            input_form.onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var input_file = input_form.select_name.value;
                console.log(" FORM SUBMIT " + input_file);
            }
         });
    });
});
```

The code renders two select fields (with the correct options), one for `JPG` and one for `TXT, ODT` file formats. But when I click any of the two submit buttons I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: input_form.select_name is undefined
```

Could anyone help me in fixing this error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried running it through the debugger?

Comment: @ControlAltDel: which debugger? sorry, newby here

Comment: Try: `var input_file = input_form.querySelector("[name="+select_name+"]").value;`

Comment: @user123892 Normally, if you press F12 in your browser, you can open up the dubugger. Set a breakpoint and run the page again

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: thank you, it works!! if you post your solution in an answer, I can accept it..

Comment: @ControlAltDel: in my browser clicking F12 increase the speakers volume :-) anyway, thank you for the time you spent replying to me but I've go the answer..

Comment: @user123892 Then you need to hold the function key and press F12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have occurs on this line:

```
var input_file = input_form.select_name.value;
```

The error message `Uncaught TypeError: input_form.select_name is undefined` means `select_name` is undefined.

`select_name` here, is not the variable you declared a couple lines above. It is a property of `input_form`, the element found by `document.getElementById(form_id);`.

The select element you wish to target is a child of that form element... So you have to target it and [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is the right method to do it.

So change it for:

```
var input_file = input_form.querySelector("[name="+select_name+"]").value;
```

Comment: Let me know if the explanations are clear and complete ;)

Comment: Yes, it is clear and useful!! thank you again